# Specifying <file> parameters in \includegraphics statement

Tags: graphics, xparse

The `\includegraphics` statement works well if the file is specified as in the `\includegraphics` statement in the code below. If however specified through the macro `\myPicspath` as in the commented-out version, a compilation error occurs:  `xparse` complains about an extra `}` inserted in the text. Yet, the statement -`\myPicspath Andromeda.jpg`- produces exactly the same string - note that the leading and trailing `*` were added to make sure there were no extra spaces occurring.

Looking through the `graphicx` document provides no clue why this should be an issue with the `\includegraphics` command, and since `xparse` is specifically mentioned in the error message I have tagged this as an expl3 issue.

Incidentally, a very similar thing happens with the `\addbibresource` command; unless hard-coded as for example in -`\addbibresource{d:/TeX/_Bibliographies/MyLibrary}`- the document will not compile.

BACKGROUND: the ability to define parameters for `\includegraphics` and `\addbibresource` through `\NewDocumentCommand` macros would assist greatly in creating documents that allow folder information to be specified in a single place and are therefore easily relocated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%-----------------------------
%RN 20 August 2015
%ISSUE: 
%COMMENTS: 
% The .jpg file is placed in .../pictures, a subfolder under the 
% folder containing this .tex file. 
%-----------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\myPicspath{O{pictures/}}{#1}

\begin{document}
*\myPicspath Andromeda.jpg*\\
%\includegraphics[angle=270,width=12cm]{\myPicspath Andromeda.jpg}
\includegraphics[angle=270,width=12cm]{pictures/Andromeda.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why not use `\graphicspath` for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\myPicspath` is not a path, because the macro is not expandable.
A simple macro definition will do:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\myPicspath}{pictures/}

\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[angle=270,width=12cm]{\myPicspath Andromeda.jpg}
  \includegraphics[angle=270,width=12cm]{pictures/Andromeda.jpg}
\end{document}
```

File names must be expandable. `\edef` can be used to test this:

```
\edef\test{\myPicspath}
\show\test
```

In interactive mode, TeX stops and shows the definition of `\test` on the console (the part between `->` and the final dot):

```
> \test=macro:
->pictures/.
```

Comment: Quite right, using \newcommand ... works for me too. If you could show me how to achieve this in LaTeX3, i.e. with a \NewDocumentCommand macro I would (a) be very happy and (b) be able to mark your response as an answer.
P.S. I am attempting to do everything I do with LaTeX3. Specifically there is more to this "document relocation issue" than meets the eye, and the whole thing is written in \NewDocumentCommand macros.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth This is not possible, because the code for the argument parsing is not expandable and the defined macro is made `\protected`, which means, it is not expandable in `\edef` or as file name.

Comment: Well, there's `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`

Comment: @heiko oberdiek I have successfully patched up my code using your `\newcommand` suggestion, and it solved the problem, so I mark your input down as an answer.

Comment: @yo I'll follow up on your suggestion after dinner.

Comment: @yo `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` does not support the optional argument of the question and `\newcommand` is much shorter.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ah forgot about that.

Comment: @heikooberdiek @yo Admittedly `\newcommand` is shorter, but I have my heart set on `LaTeX3` so followed up on yo's suggestion and realized soon enough that `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` has to end with a mandatory parameter. However, finishing my function calls with a `{}` is a small price to pay. I have rewritten my document templates accordingly and all works as it should. 
Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add a key for `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{path}{\def\Gin@path{#1}}
\def\Gin@path@default{}
\def\includegraphicsdefaultpath#1{\def\Gin@path@default{#1}}
\patchcmd\Gin@ii
  {\toks@{\Ginclude@graphics{#2}}\setkeys}
  {\toks@{\Ginclude@graphics{\Gin@path #2}}\setkeys{Gin}{path=\Gin@path@default}\setkeys}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[angle=270,width=3cm]{duck}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,path=../]{duck}
\includegraphics[angle=90,width=3cm]{duck}

\includegraphicsdefaultpath{../}

\includegraphics[angle=270,width=3cm]{duck}
\includegraphics[width=4cm,path={}]{duck}
\includegraphics[angle=90,width=3cm]{duck}

\end{document}
```

I have a `duck.jpg` both in the work directory and in the directory immediately above it; the log file will show

```
<use duck.jpg>
<use ../duck.jpg>
<use duck.jpg>
<use ../duck.jpg>
<use duck.jpg>
<use ../duck.jpg>
```

that's exactly what we desired. The command `\includegraphicsdefaultpath` sets (locally) the default path to add to a file name (empty at start up).

I didn't test interaction with `\graphicspath`.

Comment: I will consider your suggestions in some detail. Heiko Oberdiek and yo have done a great job in assisting me tonight and I now have a solution that works.